# Node.js WebRTC Socket works half the time

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, webrtc

I've just wrote a WebRTC Client/Server Application using Node.js Express & Socket.IO, but i can see the broadcasted video only if i first join the watch page and then refresh the broadcast page. Can't understand what i'm doing wroing because i'm enough inexperienced with WebRTC.

I would like to understand the correct way to write it, or at least what's wrong with my code.

Broadcast js (client):
https://jsfiddle.net/spdfyeav/1/

Watcher js (client):
https://jsfiddle.net/spdfyeav/2/

Server  Node.js Express:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

let broadcaster;
const port = 4000;

const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(server);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
/* Socket */
io.sockets.on("error", e => console.log(e));

io.sockets.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("broadcaster", () => {
    broadcaster = socket.id;
    socket.broadcast.emit("broadcaster");
  });

  socket.on("watcher", () => {
    socket.to(broadcaster).emit("watcher", socket.id);
  });

  socket.on("offer", (id, message) => {
    socket.to(id).emit("offer", socket.id, message);
  });

  socket.on("answer", (id, message) => {
    socket.to(id).emit("answer", socket.id, message);
  });

  socket.on("candidate", (id, message) => {
    socket.to(id).emit("candidate", socket.id, message);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    socket.to(broadcaster).emit("disconnectPeer", socket.id);
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Been through this.. the best option is to work with the following flow:
1) Establish peer connection (Negotiate handler and ice handler should be in-place)
2) Request media on answer (only once)

https://github.com/smitkpatel16/rsvp_vidcall

Comment: Thank you for your repo, i'll take a look and will try to understand it